# Return next specific value if a condition is met in the same column and return sum in another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas DataFrame with Two columns: Strategy and Returns.

If a 'Yes' appears in the Strategy column, I need a code what can measure the 'distance' to the next 'Close' in the same column and use the 'distance' to find out the total Return by summing up all the returns in between the two rows.

Here's the code to create a sample database

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Strategy':[0,'Close','Yes',0,'Close','Close',0,'Close','Yes','Yes','0','Close'], 'Return':[200,200,400,400,400,500,500,500,300,300,500,300]})
```

So the df should look like the table below

| Strategy | Returns |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 200 |
| Close | 200 |
| Yes | 400 |
| 0 | 400 |
| Close | 400 |
| Close | 500 |
| 0 | 500 |
| Close | 500 |
| Yes | 300 |
| Yes | 300 |
| 0 | 500 |
| Close | 300 |

And the result should be 1200(400+400+400) due to summation for for the first 3 rows and 600(300+300) for the last two rows. The sum should appear in another column. My original dataframe contains thousands of rows and there are numerous combinations of sequences of 'Yes', 'Close', and '0's with relation to each other. If a 'yes' is followed by another 'yes' before a close appears, the first 'yes' should always be taken

It should look like the table below

| Strategy | Returns | Total Returns |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 200 | 0 |
| Close | 200 | 0 |
| Yes | 400 | 0 |
| 0 | 400 | 0 |
| Close | 400 | 1200 |
| Close | 500 | 0 |
| 0 | 500 | 0 |
| Close | 500 | 0 |
| Yes | 300 | 0 |
| Yes | 300 | 0 |
| 0 | 500 | 0 |
| Close | 300 | 1100 |

I've thought of deleting all the rows above every time a 'Yes' appears and counting the number of rows till the first "Close" in the Dataframe but the method seems a little cumbersome. Surely there should be a more elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the most recent requirements and comments, this is a general method that should work for each case. This computes the total return for the smallest `Yes --- xxx ---> Close` sequences found in the data.

```python
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Strategy": [
            0,
            "Close",
            0,
            "Yes",
            0,
            0,
            "Close",
            "Close",
            0,
            "Close",
            "Yes",
            0,
            "Yes",
            "Close",
            0,
            "Yes",
            0,
            "Yes",
        ],
        "Return": [
            200,
            200,
            100,
            200,
            400,
            400,
            400,
            500,
            100,
            100,
            500,
            500,
            300,
            300,
            200,
            500,
            800,
            12,
        ],
    }
)

# Add result column and initialize it to 0:
df["Total Returns"] = 0

# Identify yes and close indexes; the [0] ensures we take the array instead of the tuple
# returned by np.where function.
yes_indexes = np.where(df["Strategy"] == "Yes")[0]
close_indexes = np.where(df["Strategy"] == "Close")[0]

already_computed = []  # store already processed values

# In this loop, for each Close value we will try to find a matching Yes value that is
# above it. This will ensure we get the closest one (min...) and also we ignore both
# Close values without Yes (sample top) and Yes without Close (sample bottom).
for idx_close in close_indexes:
    start_yes_indexes = yes_indexes[yes_indexes < idx_close]
    idx_yes = min(start_yes_indexes, key=lambda x: idx_close - x, default=None)

    # If we find a match, then compute the sum from the Yes to the Close and set the
    # value in the dataframe; also add the processed Yes/Close pair to avoid re-using the Yes,
    # else cases such as yes > close > close do not work.
    if idx_yes is not None and idx_yes not in [pair[0] for pair in already_computed]:
        df.loc[idx_close, "Total Returns"] = df.loc[idx_yes:idx_close, "Return"].sum()
        already_computed.append((idx_yes, idx_close))

print(df)
```

Result:

```
   Strategy  Return  Total Returns
0         0     200              0
1     Close     200              0
2         0     100              0
3       Yes     200              0
4         0     400              0
5         0     400              0
6     Close     400           1400
7     Close     500              0
8         0     100              0
9     Close     100              0
10      Yes     500              0
11        0     500              0
12      Yes     300              0
13    Close     300            600
14        0     200              0
15      Yes     500              0
16        0     800              0
17      Yes      12              0
```

Comment: Unfortunately thisnis only a sample dataset and I will have plenty of Close, 0, Close sequences in my real dataset =(. But Thanks

Comment: @oldradishsoip Then perhaps could you post sample data containing all possible cases? We don't know if there may be only 0, or other numbers, or other values...

Comment: @oldradishsoip There you go, it now handles Close, 0, Close cases; please note that this requires modifying values in the Return column for some Close lines. This does not change the Sum result, though. Hope it helps!

Comment: hihi...i dont think the code is correct though......for example if the dataframe starts with '0' followed by close it will calculate the sum on the close as well...lemme make my  question more specific...